# alternative to the missing setOnDateChangeListener()-function

Tags: android, datepicker

I have a DatePicker-view as well as a TimePicker-view in my layout, and everytime the date or time is changed I want to update a value. On the TimePicker I can simply set a setOnTimeChangedListener, but nothing corresponding exists for the DatePicker. A listener called OnDateChangedListener can be set in the init()-function, but it does not trigger each time the date is changed. Is there a corresponding listener, or is there a hack available to solve this problem in a satisfactory manner?

http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html
http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A listener called
>   OnDateChangedListener can be set in
>   the init()-function, but it does not
>   trigger each time the date is changed.

According to the source code, it *is* called each time the date is changed. So, try that again.

Comment: damnit, it was a stupid bug in my code. Atleast your answer convinced me the fault wasn't in the android API, making me find my bug. Thanks!